# Differential equation: $y + t\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{y}{y^2 - 1} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y + t\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{y}{y^2 - 1} \Rightarrow t\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{-y^3 + 2y}{y^2 - 1} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{t} dt = \frac{y^2 - 1}{-y^3 + 2y}dy \Rightarrow$$

$$\Rightarrow \ln |t| = - \int \frac{y^2 - 1}{y^3 - 2y}dy$$

How to solve the integral in the right part? Had it been $\frac{3y^2 - 2}{y^3 - 2y}$, then the answer would be  $\ln |y^3 - 2y|$.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28y%5E2-1%29%2F%28y%5E3-2y%29. Had been thinking of just this actually before I checked WA - make it $y^2-2$ on the numerator and the remaining $\frac{1}{y^3-2y}$ term should split.

Comment: Thank you, I know about wolframalpha, but I'm more interested in solving without using computer's help.

Comment: Well, check the answer below, but I did say how to go about it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT : We have
$$\frac{y^2-1}{y^3-2y}=\frac 12\left(\frac{1}{y}+\frac{y}{y^2-2}\right)=\frac{1}{2y}+\frac{(y^2-2)'}{4(y^2-2)}.$$